# How to perform a background job now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I want to execute this on background

```
Product.all.map { |product| product.save }
```

When I save the product will call a callback to create a new record in a table with the costs of products

I create a job for this, but if I execute `perform_now` it is not executed on background and `perform_later` executes long after.

I want to execute this right now but in background. I'm not sure if I can just execute this in a thread too.

I am using Delayed Job, here is the job

```
class UpdateProductCostsJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    Product.all.map { |product| product.save }
  end
end
```

And I want to execute every time this model is saved

```
class CostComposition < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :update_product_costs

  private

    def update_product_costs
      UpdateProductCostsJob.perform_now
    end
end
```

Comment: What are you using to run your background jobs?  Sidekiq? Resque?  Show us the code you wrote for ActiveJob.

Comment: @bkunzi01 I think he's using delayed-job (question tag)

Comment: @bkunzi01 I've updated the question

Comment: Where are you executing your `perform_now` and/or `perform_later` calls? Like `UpdateProductCostsJob.perform_now()`

Comment: @bntz Updated again (:

Comment: How are you testing that your job isn't running as it should? Redis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using rails 5, you can create a high priority queue and create the job under that queue. If you have only one queue, you can add the job to the queue as well as specify the time when you want to process that job.

```
UpdateProductCostJob.set(wait_until: Time.now + 5.minutes).perform_later
```

refer http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job